# Cannot find wrapper assembly for type library "Microsoft.Office.Core"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, warnings, ms-office

I have a warning when i build a project in Visual Studio :

```
Cannot find wrapper assembly for type library "Microsoft.Office.Core"
```

How do I get rid of it ?

Comment: check this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tolong/archive/2007/12/02/missing-office-microsoft-office-core-reference.aspx) that will help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I followed the instruction from the link below and the problem is resolved.  The problem is related to a Windows update, so after I remove the reference Microsoft.Office.Core and rebuild the project, the problem is resolved.

[Warning: The referenced component 'Microsoft.Office.Core' could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745249/warning-the-referenced-component-microsoft-office-core-could-not-be-found)

Answer (score 3):

> Missing this reference "Office = Microsoft.Office.Core"?
>
> Here is how you can add the particular reference:
>
> Step 1: Right-click your project
>
> Step 2: Select "Add reference.."
>
> Step 3: Click on the "COM" tab
>
> Step 4: Scroll down to select "**Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library**".

Source: https://web.archive.org/web/20160305201349/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tolong/archive/2007/12/02/missing-office-microsoft-office-core-reference.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have solved the same problem. Go to Add Reference. In right side search box type the missing component name or name part. You will get the checked marked items. Then uncheck then item. Click Ok. Then do the same process again. Now you will get the item is not checked. Check now. Your problem must will be solved. Basically this problem comes if your project transferred from Upper version office pc to lower version office pc.