# Warning: The referenced component 'Microsoft.Office.Core' could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, ms-office

When building one of my projects, I'm getting the following warnings:

```
Warning 3   Cannot find wrapper assembly for type library "Microsoft.Office.Core".
Warning 4   The referenced component 'Microsoft.Office.Core' could not be found.
```

Strangely, the build fails with no errors. The warnings above seem to be the problem. This started happening after I installed some Office 2007 updates from Windows Update. Before that it was building everything fine.

Has anyone experienced the same issue? Any ideas on how to solve this problem without modifying the project?

[image: After these updates, my project stopped building]

[image: This are the reference properties for Microsoft.Office.Core]

[image: References list]

Comment: Have you tried to Remove the reference add it back then rebuild the project..? also another trick you can try is to downgrade the project to .Net 3.5 build it.., then upgrade the setting to .net 4.0 and see if that fixes the issue. you may even require to check the `GAC` if it's GAC'd` and reboot the target machine as well

Comment: Yeah, removing and re-adding the reference works. But I was hoping for a solution that didn't involve modifying the project, since it's shared with other people that don't have this issue (yet).

Comment: Sometimes that's needed, never assume that because it works correctly on one environment that it will work the same across all environments especially when it comes to `Updates` I know one way around that would be to `GAC` those important `assemblies` or `shared assemblies`

Answer (score 13):

most likely one of your reference was updated to new version, so the current version can not be found.

Click "project****Properties\reference" and remove the one can not be found is ok.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a COM reference?  I'd guess the update caused the reference to be considered out of date.

If so i'd consider building the interops manually and checking them in, then adding references to the interops.  The downside is that will move the problem from compile time to run time.