# Opening windows forms application made in visual studio 2012 in vs2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2017

I have windows forms application made in visual studio 2012, and I can't open it in visual studio 2017. This is warnings that I got:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning       Cannot find wrapper assembly for type library
>   "Microsoft.Office.Core". Verify that (1) the COM component is
>   registered correctly and (2) your target platform is the same as the
>   bitness of the COM component. For example, if the COM component is
>   32-bit, your target platform must not be 64-bit.  Projekat
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning   IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project. Some
>   project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed
>   project and projects that depend on it, have been
>   disabled. Projekat        1   Active
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning       The referenced component 'Microsoft.Office.Core' could not be
>   found.    Projekat

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> most likely one of your reference was updated to new version, so the current version can not be found.
>
> Click "project****Properties\reference" and remove the one can not be found is ok.

[Warning: The referenced component 'Microsoft.Office.Core' could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745249/warning-the-referenced-component-microsoft-office-core-could-not-be-found)